# Datasource updation on adding new properties

Tags: datasource, teiid

Is there any teiid admin api to update a datasource with new properties? For e.g. I have created a datasource with some properties and now I want to add some connection properties to it, then is there a way to update the existing datasource or we need to delete and create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin api is only a shortcut for common admin operations.  For something like updating properties without add/delete, that should be done directly with the cli or a cli script.